# How to execute code returned from inspect.getsource

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, node-inspector, code-inspection

I am using python and I retrieve another piece of code from function call `inspect.getsource(func)`

I would like to execute the code and get the function's return value.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    v = 2
    return 1

import inspect
st = inspect.getsource(f)
b = exec(st)
print(b)
```

But currently I see the below shown output.

> None

What am I missing here? I would like that to execute the function and return the return value it should provide as if I were to just call the function.

Your hints & suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you have a reference to the function, then *just call the function* - retrieving the function's source and then recompiling it is likely to produce a non-working (or at least non-equivalent) function, due to the global environment being different than the module containing the original function.

Comment: @jasonharper - I need the function's code, and to be able to execute it

Comment: I’m curious, what do you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

`exec` isn't returning anything. You can instead assign something to it like so:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    v = 2
    return 1

import inspect
st = inspect.getsource(f) + '\nret=f()'
exec(st)
print(ret)  # prints 1
```

Here is another option, but it's very ugly...

```
In [65]: def f():
    ...:     a = 1
    ...:     v = 2
    ...:     return 1
    ...:

In [66]: def my_exec(func):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         code = inspect.getsource(func)
    ...:         func_name = func.__name__
    ...:         exec('global ret\n{}\nret={}()'.format(code, func_name))
    ...:         global ret
    ...:         return ret
    ...:     except IOError:
    ...:         return None
    ...:

In [67]: my_exec(f)
Out[67]: 1
```

This will create a global, `ret`, define the function and then run the function, assigning the return to `ret`. Finally it returns whatever `ret` contains. By defining your own `exec` function you will have more control over what happens before/after.

Comment: Is there any other solution to execute something that was returned from inspect?

Comment: @thebeancounter I gave another example of somewhat defining your own exec method. Is there something particular you are looking for?

Comment: Just found out that dill solves this much easier, would you like to change your answer to use it? dill.loads(dill.dumps(func))()